# issue with sql query to fetch records before current date and time

Tags: mysql, sql

I have SQL structure like `Name,expire_date,_expire_time`

and I want the query to fetch records before the current date and time.

and for that, I have used

```
SELECT * 
FROM table_name 
WHERE expire_date <= CURDATE() AND expire_time <= CURTIME()
```

and I have received data like this [image](https://www.screencast.com/t/kzpetDoSO)

as per this, I have received date before today like `2020-02-04` but with that, I have received data of `2020-02-03` because its time is before execution time

but I want data before the current date and time can anybody help me with this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to create a `DATETIME` value out of your `DATE` and `TIME` values (which you can do using [`TIMESTAMP`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_timestamp)), and then compare that to [`NOW()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_now) e.g.

```
SELECT * 
FROM table_name 
WHERE TIMESTAMP(expire_date, expire_time) <= NOW()
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use

> DATEDIFF

```
SELECT * FROM test WHERE DATEDIFF(expiry_date,CURDATE())>=0  AND expiry_time <= CURTIME();
```

Output

```
2020-02-04  05:00:00
2020-02-04  02:53:46
```